# Inserting into array from file

Tags: java, arrays, object, if-statement, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) 
    {
        if(scan.next().toLowerCase().equals("car") )
        {
            carsdata[count++] = new Car(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());
        }
    }

    while (scan2.hasNext()) 
    {
        if(scan2.next().toLowerCase().equals("motorcycle"))
        {
            motorcyclesdata[count++] = new Motorcycle(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());
        }
    }
    while (scan3.hasNext()) 
    {
        if(scan3.next().toLowerCase().equals("van"))
        {
            vansdata[count++] = new Van(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next());
        }
    }
    while (scan4.hasNext()) 
    {
        if(scan4.next().toLowerCase().equals("pickup"))
        {
            pickupsdata[count++] = new Pickup(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next());
        }
    }
```

For some reason lost to me, the motorcycle part isnt executed. I have checked by putting message boxes into that loop. Doesnt work. However the Car one works perfectly.

Here is the code im using to output into a textarea:

```
if (e.getSource() == btnMotorcycles)
        {
            vehicleTextArea.setText("");
            int i =0;

            while (motorcyclesdata[i] != null)
            {

                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].seatMaterial, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].seatColor, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].mainColor, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].price, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].passengers, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].model, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].brand, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].cc, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\t" + motorcyclesdata[i].engineCap, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("" + motorcyclesdata[i].licenseNo, 1);
                vehicleTextArea.insert("\n", 1);
                i++;
            }
            vehicleTextArea.insert("Licence No \t Engine\t CC \t Brand \t Model \t Passengers \t Price \t Material \t Paint \t Main Color \t Seat Color \t Seat Material", 0);
        }//end if
```

What am i overlooking, besides possibly the effectiveness of the code?

Comment: The code for cars and motorcycles is essentially the same (although you should probably use `scan2` instead of `scan` when you create a motorcycle). Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...Do you have 4 scanner objects reading the same source, or even four separate sources for information that belong together?

Comment: your while loops aren't checking the same scanners you are trying to read from in your constructors.

Comment: @assylias Thank you for pointing that out. That still didnt solve the initial problem of that loop not being entered..

Comment: @rogue i made four scanners in hope that the next one might read into the motorcycle loop. It isnt working.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use one scanner for reading a single data source

Comment: @rogue. I tried that at first. Didnt work.

Comment: You should not use multiple Scanner objects for a single stream, as it will be consumed. [Here's some more info around that](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO06-J.+Do+not+create+multiple+buffered+wrappers+on+a+single+InputStream). Use a single scanner object, and then the issues can be worked out from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try something like following

```
while (scan.hasNext()) 
    {
     String scanStr = scan.next();
        if(scanStr.toLowerCase().equals("car") )
        {
            carsdata[count++] = new Car(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());
        }

        if(scanStr.toLowerCase().equals("motorcycle"))
        {
            motorcyclesdata[count++] = new Motorcycle(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next());
        }

        if(scanStr.toLowerCase().equals("van"))
        {
            vansdata[count++] = new Van(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next());
        }

        if(scanStr.toLowerCase().equals("pickup"))
        {
            pickupsdata[count++] = new Pickup(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next());
        }
    }
```

also following is an observation : Just check if you want to have it the same way as you are implementing

```
    while (scan2.hasNext()) //here you are checking for Sacnner Object 2
        {
            if(scan2.next().toLowerCase().equals("motorcycle"))
            {
//here you are using Scanner Object 1 only make sure you intended to implement it to read it from scanner Object 1 only
                motorcyclesdata[count++] = new Motorcycle(scan.next(), scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt(), scan.next(), scan.next() ,scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next()); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful pointer. :) I seem to get some output on the motorcycle part now. But Cars part has issues. 
At least there is some change.. thats improvement im hoping.

Comment: In case any one is interested: Creating different methods for each of the sub-classes solved the problem :)